# Convert multiple rows to columns using T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Have a sample table like this

```
CREATE TABLE #test 
(
    ID INT, 
    NAME VARCHAR(10),
    DATE DATE
)

INSERT INTO #TEST 
VALUES (1, 'Test', '2023-01-01'),
       (1, 'Test1', '2023-03-01'),
       (2, 'abc', '2023-01-01'),
       (2, 'abc1', '2023-03-01')
```

I have tried this but not getting the data I wanted, please suggest  what I am doing wrong here.

```
SELECT 
  [0], [1]  
FROM  
(
  SELECT NAME, ID ,DATE 
  FROM #TEST
) AS SourceTable  
PIVOT  
(  
  MAX(ID)  
  FOR NAME IN ([0], [1])  
) AS PivotTable;
```

I'm expecting results like this

[image]

Comment: assign a row number to eahc ID based on date descending then join two sets based on ID where 1 is RN 1 and 2nd is RN2  assuming you only have 2 results per ID.

Comment: What if there are more than two IDs? Do you want the columns to continue for as many IDs as you have?

Answer (score 2):

Another, yet similar, approach involves the aggregation in place of the join operation.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE) AS rn 
    FROM #test
)
SELECT ID, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN NAME END) AS [DATE], 
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN DATE END) AS [0],
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN NAME END) AS [DATE1], 
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN DATE END) AS [2]
FROM cte
GROUP BY ID
```

**Output**:

| ID | DATE | 0 | DATE1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test | 2023-01-01 | Test1 | 2023-03-01 |
| 2 | abc | 2023-01-01 | abc1 | 2023-03-01 |

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/QeweO-7g).

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/fcyMmO9h)

If we can assume there are just 2 rows per ID...  no need to use a pivot.  if however, it is "n" sets of dates long, you need dynamic SQL as the results are a dynamic pivot.  but as you limit your results to [0],[1] i assumed it's only 2.

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT *, row_Number() over (partition by ID order by [Date]) RN 
             FROM #Test)
SELECT A.Name, A.ID, A.Date as ADate, B.Name, B.Date as BDate
FROM CTE A
LEFT JOIN CTE B
 on A.ID = B.ID
WHERE A.RN = 1
and B.RN = 2
```

Giving us:

| Name | ID | ADate | Name | BDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Test | 1 | 2023-01-01 | Test1 | 2023-03-01 |
| abc | 2 | 2023-01-01 | abc1 | 2023-03-01 |

Comment: thanks for you reply , my data is going to be more than 1, 2, some times the name column will be more than 5 records.

Comment: Well in that case you're going to need to look into dynamic SQL as you have to determine the number of header columns at run time then.  This lends itself to dynamic SQL and what is refered to as a dynamic pivot.